# Create PHP associative array from another array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, associative-array

I m just wondering how to create an array from another array. I have this multidimensional array.

```
Array(
    [0] => Array(
            [c] => Array(
                    [0] => Array(
                            [v] => Commercial
                        )    
                    [1] => Array(
                            [v] => 2
                        )    
                )    
        )

    [1] => Array(
            [c] => Array(
                    [0] => Array(
                            [v] => Infrastructure
                        )    
                    [1] => Array(
                            [v] => 47
                        )    
                )    
        )

    [2] => Array(
            [c] => Array(
                    [0] => Array(
                            [v] => Tourist & Recreational
                        )    
                    [1] => Array(
                            [v] => 3
                        )    
                )    
        ) 
)
```

and I want to dynamically create the following array from the above array.

```
Array
(
    [Commercial] => 2
    [Infrastructure] => 47
    [Tourist & Recreational] =3 
)
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: There is pretty much no value in having each array member have a single sub array, like `0 => array( 'c' => array` You could use array_column to get what you have in mind if the actual values were at the same level.

Comment: Some context about how you start of with such a strange array structure would be helpful. Arguably anything that can generate the first array can generate the second more easily.

Comment: The first array is created for google charting. For some reason I need to have the second array created from the first one (JSON object).

Answer (score 1):

Suppose your above array is in $array. So,

```
$new_arr = array();
foreach($array as $val){
  if(isset($val['c'][0]['v']) && isset($val['c'][1]['v'])){
     $new_arr[$val['c'][0]['v']] = $val['c'][1]['v'];
  }
}
print_r($new_arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

the array_walk_recursive() function is your answer in this case, this solution is a bit dirty, but the general function would run only on Leaf nodes, so it's definitely the way to go:

```
<?php


$arr = [
    0 => [
            'c' => [
                    0 => [
                            'v' => 'Commercial'
                        ]    ,
                    1 => [
                            'v' => 2
                        ]    ,
                ]    
        ],

    1 => [
            'c' => [
                    0 => [
                            'v' => 'Infrastructure'
                        ]    ,
                    1 => [
                            'v' => 47
                        ]    ,
                ]    
        ],

    2 => [
            'c' => [
                    0 => [
                            'v' => 'Tourist & Recreational'
                        ]    ,
                    1 => [
                            'v' => 3
                        ]    ,
                ]    
        ] 
];
global $array_clean;
function pluck_leaves( $item, $key ) {
    global $array_clean;
    if ( is_numeric( $item ) ) {
        if ( isset( $array_clean['temp_key'] ) ) {
            $array_clean[$item] = $array_clean['temp_key'];
            unset( $array_clean['temp_key'] );
        } else {
            $array_clean[$item] = null;
        }
    } else {
        $last_key = key(end($array_clean));

        reset( $array_clean );
        if ($array_clean[ $last_key ] !== null) {
            $array_clean[ $last_key ] = $item;
        } else {
            $array_clean['temp_key'] = $item;
        }

    }
}
array_walk_recursive($arr, 'pluck_leaves' );

var_dump($array_clean);
?>
```